# How to convert json object string to plain string using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I have a json below,

```
{
    "test1": "test123",
    "test2": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }
}
```

I want to map this to below class using Jackson library.

```java
class TestClass {
    String test1;
    String test2;
}
```

But I can't do this because test2 is an json object, not String. I want to map both test1 and test2 to string

```
String test1; // "test123"
String test2; // "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"
```

What should I do?

Comment: How about creating the expected structure for test2 as Class Test2 and then implement a toString to serialize it the way you'd like it?

Comment: @AG I have to process test2 separately due to the restriction on API. So... I think I can't make instance for test2 at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom deserializer.

---

```
class TestClass {
    String test1;
    String test2;

    public TestClass(String test1, String test2) {
        this.test1 = test1;
        this.test2 = test2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<TestClass> {

    public MyDeserializer() {
        this(TestClass.class);
    }

    public MyDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public TestClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        return new TestClass(node.get("test1").asText(), node.get("test2").toString());
    }
}
```

---

**Test**

```
String json = "{" +
        "    \"test1\": \"test123\"," +
        "    \"test2\": {" +
        "        \"a\": 1," +
        "        \"b\": 2" +
        "    }" +
        "}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(
        new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(TestClass.class, new MyDeserializer()));
TestClass testClass = mapper.readValue(json, TestClass.class);
System.out.println(testClass.test1);
System.out.println(testClass.test2);
```

**Output**

```
test123
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create java class with values that corresponds to you json object. In your  case `test1` is String object and `test2` requires you to create new class that will hold two strings '`a`' and `b`.  With your approach you will lose clear data access when converting two values into one String.

Please refer to those links for more information

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-json-to-java-object
- https://stackabuse.com/how-to-convert-json-object-to-java-object-with-jackson/